# Problems swapping UIViewControllers when orientation changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegation

I have a single view app with 2 view controllers to present different layouts for portrait and landscape. I have set up the orientation changed notifications and can successfully display the landscape view on the first orientation change.

1st Problem:
When I change the orientation back to portrait the portrait view is not displayed.

2nd Problem: 
When I change the orientation back to landscape the landscape view displays but I get a warning:

Attempt to present CalculatorViewControllerLandscape on CalculatorViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy.

I have been through the apple documentation and several posts with similar problems and have figured out that the answer lies in the use of delegation but I have not been able to get delegation set up correctly. Here is my attempt:

CalculatorViewControllerLandscape.h

```
@protocol SecondControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@end
.....
@property(nonatomic, weak) id <SecondControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

CalculatorViewController.h

```
@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController <SecondControllerDelegate> {
....
}
@property (strong) CalculatorViewControllerLandscape *landscapeVC;
```

CalculatorViewCalculator.m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification     
                                           object:nil];
// register as a delegate
self.navigationController.delegate = (id)self;
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
           !isShowingLandscapeView)        
    {
        NSLog(@"Orientation has changed to landscape");
        // code here to show landscape storyboard
        UIStoryboard *landscapeStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LandscapeStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *landscapeViewController = [landscapeStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
         [self presentViewController:landscapeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
         isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }    
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&             
         isShowingLandscapeView)        
    {
        NSLog(@"Orientation has changed to portrait");   
    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}
```

I've been working on this for several hours and have checked all posts which similar problems but I still can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to handle rotation events in a single `UIViewController`, rather than using two separate ones. I'm not familiar with interface builder, but programmatically you can override `-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews;` and lay out your view appropriately based on `self.interfaceOrientation`. I recommend you do it that way.

However, in answer to your question:

try changing

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

to

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

This may fix the 2nd problem as well, because the old landscape view controller not being properly dismissed.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your help. Almost there. When I changed the code as you suggested, it got rid of the warning and now the view changes correctly for both landscape orientations and portrait but not Upside Down. I don't understand why UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait would treat upside down any different to portrait. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Solved the upside problem by putting  "if (deviceOrientation != 2)" // if it's not upsidedown. into the orientationChanged method so nothing happens if the orientation changes to upsidedown. I also removed all the delegation code and it still works so no requirement for delegation to get this to work. I haven't had time yet to try to get it to work using a single UIViewController as suggested by Nick but that's next on my list.